# How to make a script to download and configure apps?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script

I need to write a script to avoid the chore of downloading things and having to configure everything, every time I make a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Is bash the recommended tool or language for this use case?

Comment: have you looked at http://ninite.com/linux/?

Comment: Most system level config is stored in /etc/ and your personal configuration is in /home/<yourusername>/  Backing these up before a fresh install would make reconfiguration more straightforward.  /home is ideally a separate partition from the system in any case.